# Batch - Reading an entire line -- including whitespaces

Tags: batch-file

I want to read an entire line of a text file into the batch window. The program I am using now only reads the first word, up to the next white space character.

Comment: What program are you using now ... ? Please add more details to your question to allow people to help you.

Answer (score 1):

In the For command you can specify delimiters. If you don't tab and space are the delimiters.

```
for /f "delims=" %A in (somefile.txt) do echo hi
```

As delims is set to nothing, the quotes enclose the *options*, it will read whole lines.